# Angular: How to programmatically trigger DOM events, like mouse click?

Tags: angular, dom-events

I want to raise a `click` [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) programmatically, for example, from an Angular Component to simulate a mouse click. Is this possible and how? I didn't find any existing question on this here.

The `DOM` element will be some element like a button in a Component template.

Comment: some more downvotes please but with explanation..

Comment: This question has been asked on Stack Overflow with respect to vanilla JavaScript, but not in an Angular context. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular, you would obtain an [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) using [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). Then you could either call `HTMLElmenent.click()` or `HTMLElement.dispatchEvent(event)`.

See [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raise-dom-event-so-58051215?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

## Option 1: Use HTMLElement.click()

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Test Angular Programmatic Click Event</h1>

  <div #namedElement (click)="showAlert('Clicked namedElement')">
    Named element
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('namedElement', {static: false}) namedElement: ElementRef;

  public constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.namedElement.nativeElement.click();
  }

  public showAlert(msg: string) {
    alert(msg)
  }
}
```

## Option 2: Use HTMLElement.dispatchEvent()

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Test Angular Programmatic Click Event</h1>

  <div #namedElement (click)="showAlert('Clicked namedElement')">
    Named element
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('namedElement', {static: false}) namedElement: ElementRef;

  public constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });

    this.namedElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  public showAlert(msg: string) {
    alert(msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is document object available in component ts file ?

Comment: and even if it is provided as a global object, is it a good practice to use it ?

Comment: one important point is that I tried it and I don't see angular change detection working with it. Maybe the native element trigger actions are being ignored....

Comment: pls let me know if you want to take a look at the snippet ? The event is getting fired and event handler is getting invoked, however inside event handler, I change a property because of which template should have changed but it doesn't.